# Android NaviagtionDrawer Item Text Alignment

Tags: android, android-studio, navigation-drawer, android-xml

I am created NavigationView Like this
[image: My Navigation View ScreenShot]

,and this is my xml code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/top_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".Dashbored">

<include
android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
layout="@layout/tool_bar">
</include>

<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_below="@+id/tool_bar"
android:elevation="7dp"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="end">


<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">


<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/frame_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<include layout="@layout/f_home_screen" />

</FrameLayout>


</LinearLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
android:id="@+id/nav_view"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="end"
android:background="#0284fe"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
app:itemBackground="@drawable/drawer_backg"
app:itemIconTint="@color/drawer_item"
app:itemTextAppearance="@style/NavDrawerTextStyle"
app:itemTextColor="@color/windowBackground"
app:menu="@menu/main_drawer" />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to set Item text alignment center like this

[image: I need a output like this]

This is my menu xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><menu 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<group android:checkableBehavior="single">
<item
android:id="@+id/nav_inspec_rpt"
android:title="INSPECTION REPORTS"
/>
<item
android:id="@+id/nav_action"
android:title="ACTION ITEMS"
/>
<item
android:id="@+id/nav_appoint"
android:title="APPOINTMENTS" />
<item
android:id="@+id/nav_applst"
android:title="MAIN APPOINTMENTS" />
<item
android:id="@+id/nav_logout"
android:title="LOG OUT" />
</group>
```

I want to get output like second Image, please help me, I tried to give styles in style.xml like this, but I don't know how to align text, I tried it a different way by google it, but no luck. :(

```
<style name="NavDrawerTextStyle" parent="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat">
<item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
<item name="android:textSize">16dp</item>
<item name="android:fontFamily">serif</item>
<item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

Thanks

Comment: At last I found a solution, I created a Listview instead of menu and give text alignment, Its working fine,Thanks

Comment: I gave my solution below , please check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am created Listview instead of a menu.

This is my xml code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/top_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".Dashbored">

<include
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    layout="@layout/tool_bar">

</include>


<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tool_bar"
    android:elevation="7dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="end">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frame_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <include layout="@layout/f_home_screen" />

        </FrameLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:maxWidth="250dp"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:background="#0284fe"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/navheader"
                layout="@layout/nav_header" />

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/lst_menu_items"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:divider="@null"
                android:dividerHeight="0dp"

                />
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Then I used a custom adpater and textview , then I aligned my text gravity center.

This is my final output
[image: This is my output]

Answer (score 7):

You can `center-align` the menu items dynamically using `SpannableString` in your activity:

```
int positionOfMenuItem = 0; //or any other postion

MenuItem item = menu.getItem(positionOfMenuItem);

SpannableString s = new SpannableString(settingsItemTitle);

s.setSpan(new AlignmentSpan.Standard(Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER), 0, s.length(), 0);

item.setTitle(s);
```

Comment: That's correct, this is better than creating a `ListView`

Comment: The best answer! Also, I agitate to use this approach in link with kotlin extensions. My answer will be here (below or above) in the post.

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin extension:

```
fun Menu.centerTitles() {
    for (i in 0 until size()) {
        val item = getItem(i)
        SpannableString(item.title).also {
            it.setSpan(AlignmentSpan.Standard(Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_CENTER), 0, it.length, 0)
            item.title = it
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
navigationViewMain!!.menu.centerTitles()
```

P.S. It's the improved answer by Heena Arora

Answer (score 0):

Use `style="@style/MaterialAlertDialog.MaterialComponents.Title.Panel.CenterStacked"` attrib for navigation view as :

```
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
            app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
            app:menu="@menu/main_activity_navigator_items"
            android:background="@color/appbgcolor"
style="@style/MaterialAlertDialog.MaterialComponents.Title.Panel.CenterStacked"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try setting `android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"` instead of `android:layout_gravity="end"` in your NavigationView.

Comment: Hi Nicolas, I tried this way, But its effect to the NavigationView, not to the text in items.

Answer (score -1):

`android:gravity="center"` sets the gravity of the content of the View its used on.
`android:layout_gravity` sets the gravity of the View or Layout in its parent.

Comment: It is not possible in Navigation drawer when item added as a menu. Example: app:menu="@menu/navigation_items"